# Macintosh Python: 64-bit vs 32-bit problems

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort through a whole host of problems arising from upgrading my macintosh to 10.6. Most of the tools I need work, but a couple (scipy, wxpython) do not, and give error messages that are highly suggestive of my messing up something with 64-bit and 32-bit binaries.

I'm currently running Python 2.7. I don't know whether it is a 32-bit or a 64-bit version. How do I tell?

What I'm most concerned about is that I have some bizarre mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit, and that I should scrap everything and reinstall. If I do this, and I want to avoid as many build problems as possible, do I (1) install the 32-bit version, (2) install the 64-bit version and make sure everything I build is 64-bit enabled, or (3) something else.

I've tried without luck to find web pages regarding this, since other people must have stumbled over these issue, but I apologize if I'm rehashing old issues here. I've also tried very hard not to type the offensive statement "I don't care about 32-bit vs 64-bit, I just want Python to *work*", but, in effect, that's what I'm asking here.

Heaps of gratitude to whomever can help me sort through this, and apologies if I'm just being dense.

Comment: Run this script: `import platform; platform.architecture()`. What does it say?

Comment: is numpy etc compiled with both i386 and x86_64 architectures?

Comment: >>> import platform; platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')

Comment: @GWW - I don't know: I think I just did the default python setup.py build process.

Answer (score 1):

I also had major problems upgrading, so you are not alone, only a bit late.

To figure out what kind of binary you have, the `file` command is your friend:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/bin/python (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/usr/local/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

You may also be advised to use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or (even better) [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/).

If you are already using MacPorts and nothing works anymore, you may even want to uninstall it and start from scratch with Homebrew. It gets you quickly to a point where hell is less hot. After that you only need to figure out how to compile that important esoteric library to the right architecture.

Comment: I've been meaning to try HomeBrew or Ports for a while. Maybe I should just jump in. I was never all that happy with Fink, so I've been compiling my own since then.

Answer (score 1):

For wxPython, try using this shebang as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/arch -arch i386 python2.7
```

Or running from the command line with

```
arch -arch i386 python2.7 yourScript.py
```

Basically, your python executable should include both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, and the 'arch' command tells the system which one to run with.